# How can I submit data from multiple forms with only one submit button using POST?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having some trouble with a code I have, this is a simplified version of it:

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test1" />
</form>
asd
<form name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    echo $_POST['test1'] . $_POST['test2'];
}
?>
```

I hope this makes clear what I am trying to do.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is the purpose behind different forms?

Comment: Why do you need two forms when you are not using 'submit' on one of them. Is it not possible for you to include all inputs inside single form and use submit for them?

Comment: You have your inputs in two forms. And according your code, you are submitting just the second one. Hence, you will grab `$_POST['test2']` but no `$_POST['test1']`.

Comment: If you really want to do this you should use JavaScript/AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you could solve this issue of seperating your data on the PHP side would be to add a name array to your inputs. For example:

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test[1]" />
    <input type="text" name="test[2]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then after you submit to a PHP page you can access them by:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    echo $_POST['test'][1] . $_POST['test2'][2];
}
```

If you absolutely have to have separate form tags for some unknown reason, then you can also do this using AJAX. Add a class to your submit buttons and bind a click event to this using vanilla JavaScript and or jQuery, cancel the  normal form action, and post to a standalone php page. AJAX will return w/e you write back. Here is an Example of the JavaScript:

```
jQuery('.submit-button').click(function() {

    //Find all input fields in the form and store them
    var fields = jQuery(this).parent().find(':input').serializeArray(),
        url = '/somepage/somepath/',
        returnJSON,
        ajaxRequestHandler;

    //Stop the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault(); 

    //Start AJAX request
    ajaxRequestHandler = jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: fields
    });

    //Error Hanlder
    ajaxRequestHandler.fail(function (returnData) {
        console.log('failure');
    });

    //Success Handler
    ajaxRequestHandler.done(function (returnData) {
       //Display a message to the html page.
    });


});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test1" class="submit-button" />

</form>

<form name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
```

You then need to setup a standalone PHP page or a new method in your controller if your using MVC. You also need to make sure this PHP page is secure.

Comment: Know this is old but.... surely just start your form then use the while to spit out the inputs??